# do not show "file overwriten" message in python

Tags: python

I need to use pyfits (http://www.stsci.edu/institute/software_hardware/pyfits) to open/write some spectra for the work I am doing. Problem is, everytime I use the "writeto" function to write a .fits file and it overwrites it, I get a "Overwrite existing file: XXX.fits" message on the screen. Is it possible to tell the program to not show this partiular message?

I already checked and could not find a keyword for the "writeto" function that would  deactivate this message, so I was thinking if there was anyway to tell python to redirect all output (except if it is an error) of a particular function to something like /dev/null or similar.

Worst case scenario, I thought that maybe using "logging" and redirect all output to a file and thats it..

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library uses the Python [`warnings` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html) to emit a warning when you 'clobber' an existing file.

You can use that same module to suppress the warning:

```
import warnings

with warnings.catch_warnings():
    warnings.simplefilter("ignore")
    pyfits.writeto(...)
```

Using the `catch_warnings()` context manager suppresses all warnings that `pyfits.writeto()` might raise. You can also configure filters for specific messages to be ignored:

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='Overwriting existing file .*', module='pyfits\.hdu.*')
```

would ignore messages that start with `Overwriting existing file` raised by modules that start with `pyfits.hdu` for example.

Comment: Cool! I used the first option, and it worked perfectly! In my case it works better than the 2nd option as I call 'pyfits.writeto()' inside a function and the for the 2nd option I had to insert the code inside the function and would affect it each time I called the function and not the particular instance I wanted. Just to make sure I understood it correctly, using 'warnings.catch_warnings()' in a 'with' block, will only affect what is inside the block, correct? Thanks!

Comment: @jorgehumberto: Correct. But the other method you can put at the top of your module or in the main module of your project. It is then executed only once, but then applies  to any future calls to `pyfits.writeto()`

Comment: In my case it is not handy as I only want to ignore the warning on a specific instance of the program, but not on the whole program (reason is, I have a progress bar to track the writing of multiple *.fit files, and in that case the progress is more important than overwriting alerts). Anyway, second version might come handy in the future :)

Comment: In which case the context manager is probably what you wanted. :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`warnings.filterwarnings`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/warnings.html#warnings.filterwarnings) to suppress the messages. Simply add

```
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='Overwriting existing file')
```